# In Spark, how to convert DataFrame with SparseVector into RDD[Vector]?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Following [this example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tf-idf) I've computed TF-IDF weightings for some documents. Now I want to use `RowMatrix` to calculate document similarities. But I'm having trouble fitting the data into the right format. What I have right now is a DataFrame whose rows have (String,SparseVector) as the two columns' types. I'm supposed to convert this to `RDD[Vector]` which I thought would be as easy as:

```
features.map(row => row.getAs[SparseVector](1)).rdd()
```

But I get this error:

```
<console>:58: error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a
Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case
classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for 
serializing other types will be added in future releases.
```

Importing `spark.implicits._` makes no difference.

So what's going on? I'm surprised that Spark doesn't know how to encode its own vector datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert to `RDD` before `map`.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg._

val df = Seq((1, Vectors.sparse(1, Array(), Array()))).toDF

df.rdd.map(row => row.getAs[Vector](1))
```